# Qt Best Control For Multi Column List?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qlistview, model-view

I want to display a multi column list, so when one column is filled to the bottom of the window subsequent items will be displayed in the next column, something like this:

```
Item1 Item4 Item7
Item2 Item5 Item8
Item3 Item6 Item9
```

If the window is resized the items should change columns so the list doesn't extent beyond the bottom of the window.

I tried this with a `QTableWidget`, but it's quite slow when you resize the window because you have to move all the `QTableWidgetItems` to new positions, and maintaining which items are selected is a bit of a pain.

Is there a better control for doing this, or is `QTableWidget` the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`QGridView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html). It will work with [Qt's Model/View Paradigm](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) accepting a [`ListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#listmodel).

Based on the grid layout that you have specified you'll want to set the [`flow` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#flow-prop) to `FlowTopToBottom` to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Assoluto Yup, this one's actually a special one in that it's in QtQuick 2.5 But for most of your Models/Views you can find them in this list: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-view-classes